# Migrate SharePoint App-Domain from 2013 to 2016

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, 2016, migration

I have a SharePoint 2013 with lots of SharePoint- and Provider-Hosted apps. This must be migrated to SharePoint 2016. How do i best handle migration of the App-Domain?

**Some more information what we do:**

- We perform several Test-Migrations and one Big-Bang productive migration
- WebApplication URLs must stay the same. For testing we work with HOSTS-entries on our new SharePoint-Servers and on the Test-Clients. During PROD-Migration, we will change DNS-Entries to SP2016 Farm.

**I see two possibilities:**

1. Also create HOSTS-Entries for every App. As far as i know, i cannot use Wildcard in HOSTS (`*.apps.tld`)
2. Migrate to a new AppDomain (`*.apps2016.tld`). This seems to be a good choice, but i am a little scared things might break during migration when a new AppDomain is in place on the new farm.

Any practical experience is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this question on my experience after we worked through migration:

**We used Option 1**. We filtered out all installed Apps and created HOSTS-Entries for each App-Domain. We didn't evaluate Option 2, so i cannot say if this would also be a valid migration-path.